# Joomla template changing and module positions

Tags: templates, joomla, module

I assigned two different joomla templates based on IP geolocation. That is working fine but I have a problem with modules. Both templates have very different module positions. Currently I need to make two copies of my modules and assign each copy to one template. I want to avoid this. Is there a way, I can assign module positions based on template in Joomla?

Please comment if you need more clarification about the question.

Comment: The dirty way is to change the names of the module positions to be the same on both templates. You can do it from the templatedetails.xml file

Comment: Aha, good suggestion. I'll try that. Is there a proper way to do that by the way? Without changing the .xml file?